# Citing line numbers of a one-page text in MLA format

Tags: citations, writing

Is it considered a valid MLA format for an in-text citation, where a work only has one page, to use the line numbers? Say, (LastName, AuthoredWork 2-3) for instance to cite the quoted lines 2-3 from AuthoredWork by the author? If not, what is the appropriate in-text way to do this for a work with only one page?

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. MLA doesn't require in-text citations to have the author's last name and the title of the article. The format is simply (lastname #pagenumber) or, if the author's last name isn't present, the first thing which occurs in the citation (article title, etc).
2. MLA also doesn't require line-numbers, nor really allow for it. In text citations are primarily there to help your reader understand the text, and adding line numbers would just prove confusing to readers. Given that it's only 1 page of material, you don't need it either, as the quote will likely be super easy to find for readers.